# One customer had a broken link in our email on Outlook

Tags: html, email, outlook, hyperlink, html-email

A customer reported an issue where the link in an email they received was not displayed properly. Despite multiple checks on different Outlook accounts, the link appeared to be functioning normally. However, the customer reported seeing HTML code instead of a clickable link within the email's table. The customer sent us a copy of the email, and i could see that the button instead of containing all well done  has this:

```
[%3ca%20href=]https://app.mydomain.com/unit?user=70a92653-555c-4daf-966d-8b2c062e133c&unit=97aec2fb-e21a-47b2-9731-be0c2a9acabd&campaign=f0e0ef90-ac23-465a-8f02-42e4a77feb1b&cohort=ed0307f6-31d7-4537-a3d5-a1c6a35b19a9" style=" display: block; height: 100%; width: 100%; text-decoration: none; color: #ffffff; "> Click to Access
```

It's like that outlook attemped to rewrite the <a href= itself breaking it all. Do anyone had similar troubles with Outlook for Windows? Is it an antivirus, or do we need to ensure something in our <!-- mso comment?

Answer (score 0):

Check for any additional software in Outlook like COM or web add-ins installed (or VBA macros) that could cause such issues. For example, most antivirus software adds their  bits to Outlook.

Answer (score 0):

Outlook.com specifically will turn a link that doesn't have a proper protocol at the start into this: [www.sitewithoutinitialprotocol.com]Text for Link

So perhaps what is happening is it doesn't think the link you've written is correct. What's the code in the initial email for the link? The href attribute must have a http:// or https:// (though it does look like you have this).

Perhaps also check the character/characters in this text, it may be there's a hidden non-breaking space or something unusual. You can paste it all into regexr.com, into the 'expression' area, and check each character precisely.